# Cannot assign value of type 'STPPaymentMethodCardParams' to type 'STPCardParams'

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I updated to latest Stripe.

How to create a source from STPPaymentMethodCardParams

Comment: You don't, you create a PaymentMethod instead, using https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAPIClient.html#/c:objc(cs)STPAPIClient(im)createPaymentMethodWithParams:completion: [PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) are a new abstraction that replace Tokens/Cards/Sources and the new version of stripe-ios uses them by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced same issue when upgrading Stripe POD I've changed my code and it works fine. May be it will help you

```
let cardParams: STPCardParams = STPCardParams()
                       cardParams.number = mCardText!.cardNumber
                       cardParams.expMonth = mCardText!.expirationMonth
                       cardParams.expYear = mCardText!.expirationYear
                       cardParams.cvc = mCardText!.cvc
STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams, completion: { (token, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {}
        else {}
    })
```

Comment: Is this PCI compliant?

Comment: @Mot yes PCI compliant

Comment: Thank you. I wish Stripe would add this to their SDK.